# How can I write following inductive proposition in Coq without violating strict positivity?

Tags: coq

```
S e := 
| def: (forall e', S e' -> S (App e e')) -> S e
```

I am trying to write logical relations based proof of strong normalization in Coq.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to model, but the solution is to model in a different way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it as a Fixpoint over the structure of expressions:

```
Inductive expr :=
| Var (n:nat)
| Abs (n:nat) (e:expr)
| App (e1 e2: expr).

Fixpoint S (e:expr) : Prop :=
  match e with
  | Var n => True
  | Abs n e => True
  | App e1 e2 => S e2
  end.
```

Note that you can't say something like `forall e', S e' -> subst e n e'` in the `Abs` case because it doesn't recurse on a subterm. Instead, though, you can recurse on the structure of the type of `e`. I worked on something like this for Gödel's System T (lambda calculus with recursion over natural numbers): see https://github.com/tchajed/goedel-t/blob/master/SystemT.v#L538.

Comment: How is this equivalent to OP's type?

Comment: It's really not, but I don't know how to make the original example terminate - it actually looks unfounded to me, and in any case is vacuous with only that constructor. I was hoping to just illustrate one possible solution, but it depends on what the actual logical relation is.

Comment: I seem to vaguely remember [a trick](https://gist.github.com/gallais/fbba881e09aa349ea59093d8bbf153a4) for when the inductive definition is in `Prop` (which is the case for @abhishek apparently). Not sure whether it's usable in practice.